# SQL Subtract two rows from each other in same column to get a result

Tags: php, sql, date, window-functions

I am running many energy readers which collects data with intervals of 5min. To get power used between two time stamps, I need to subtract older data from the newer data.

I am new to SQl, so I would like to ask what SQL syntax do I need to use to get a total sum between two Values.

Database Structure example:

[image: Data Table example]

Thank you very much.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results *in the question* as text tables, not images.  Add an appropriate database tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would typically use window function `lead()` or `lag()` - if your database supports that.

The following query puts on each row the difference with the previous value of the same equipment:

```
select
    t.*,
    t_energy_a - lag(t_energy_a) over(partition by meter_id order by dod) diff
from mytable t
```

Comment: Thank you kindly. This has worked. This is exactly what I needed. I am new, so all these small things I am picking up from people such as your self or internet. It is sometime quicker to get advice from someone else as they know exactly what to use where I don't even know what to look for. Thank you for your help.